# Declaration expected error for System.Xml.Linq.XDocument in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, adventureworks, xml-literals, system.xml

I am trying to learn about XML literals in VB. In a "learning" project which based on a console application template the following compiles and runs without error (and without any special Imports statements nor references added):

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim db As New AdventureWorksDataContext
    Dim stores = <?xml version="1.0"?>
                 <stores>
                     <%= From vStoreWithDemographics In db.vStoreWithDemographics _
                         Select <store>
                                    <ID>
                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.BusinessEntityID %>
                                    </ID>
                                    <Name>
                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.Name %>
                                    </Name>
                                    <AnnualSales>
                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.AnnualSales %>
                                    </AnnualSales>
                                    <BankName>
                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.BankName %>
                                    </BankName>
                                    <SquareFeet>
                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.SquareFeet %>
                                    </SquareFeet>
                                    <NumberEmployees>
                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.NumberEmployees %>
                                    </NumberEmployees>
                                </store>
                     %>
                 </stores>
    stores.Save("c:\stores.xml")
    Process.Start("c:\stores.xml")
End Sub
```

End Module

Yet I tried repeating the same in a new project based on a Windows Forms app and I get errors on the last 2 statements (both saying only "**Declaration expected**"; also note: I compared the References for the console app with those provided by default for the winforms app and added System.Data.Linq then given the error I added 2 Imports statements but I still get the errors).

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Xml.Linq.XDocument
Public Class Form1
Dim db As New AdventureWorksDataContext
Dim stores = <?xml version="1.0"?>
             <stores>
                 <%= From vStoreWithDemographics In db.vStoreWithDemographics _
                     Select <store>
                                <ID>
                                    <%= vStoreWithDemographics.BusinessEntityID %>
                                </ID>
                                <Name>
                                    <%= vStoreWithDemographics.Name %>
                                </Name>
                                <AnnualSales>
                                    <%= vStoreWithDemographics.AnnualSales %>
                                </AnnualSales>
                                <BankName>
                                    <%= vStoreWithDemographics.BankName %>
                                </BankName>
                                <SquareFeet>
                                    <%= vStoreWithDemographics.SquareFeet %>
                                </SquareFeet>
                                <NumberEmployees>
                                    <%= vStoreWithDemographics.NumberEmployees %>
                                </NumberEmployees>
                            </store>
                 %>
             </stores>
    stores.Save("c:\stores.xml")                   'error here
    Process.Start("c:\stores.xml")                 'error here
End Class
```

Please tell me what I am missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second block of code is not inside of a method. It needs to be inside of a `Sub` or `Function`:

```
 Public Class Form1
      Public Sub SomeFoo()
           Dim db As New AdventureWorksDataContext
           Dim stores = <?xml version="1.0"?>
                           <stores>
                                <%= From vStoreWithDemographics In db.vStoreWithDemographics _
                                     Select <store>
                                                   <ID>
                                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.BusinessEntityID %>
                                                   </ID>
                                                   <Name>
                                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.Name %>
                                                   </Name>
                                                   <AnnualSales>
                                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.AnnualSales %>
                                                   </AnnualSales>
                                                   <BankName>
                                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.BankName %>
                                                   </BankName>
                                                   <SquareFeet>
                                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.SquareFeet %>
                                                   </SquareFeet>
                                                   <NumberEmployees>
                                                        <%= vStoreWithDemographics.NumberEmployees %>
                                                   </NumberEmployees>
                                              </store>
                                %>
                           </stores>
           stores.Save("c:\stores.xml")
           Process.Start("c:\stores.xml")
      End Sub
 End Class
```

And then at some point in your application something will call `SomeFoo`.